# Including Js file form http (other domain ) to my domain which is https server

Tags: https, include, load, external

I have issue with oil price
which we were getting form below script/ external website link :-

But Due to SSL , we have changed link from below way

which is perfectly working on chrome browser but on other browser script not loading properly

(Have you any idea regarding this how we can resolve )
I am doing this in Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

From an https website you can't include js from an http host. (Active mixed content is blocked)

- If you need to include a script, host it yourself (or use a CDN provider with https)
- If you need to include a data provider, you need to proxy the request :
  https://you.website/get_data.js returns the content of https://the.other.website/get_data.js

Comment: Is der not any other way to do this ?

Comment: What is that script? A library like jQuery or it contains data?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http//www.oil-price.net/TABLE3/gen.php?lang=en"></script>

But Due to SSL , we have changed link from below way
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.oil-price.net/TABLE3/gen.php?lang=en"></script>
But its not working

Comment: the // means https:// because your website use https. If oil-price doesn't support https you have two solutions : convince them to use it or proxy the data (I've completed my answer about that)

Comment: how i can proxy the data .( I have forwarded the request to use https but still no response from them )or Are we have any other way to remove https to http for one page from .htacess